# Invalid use of non-static data member error

Tags: c++

I was solving a problem and got stuck into this error in a class.

> invalid use of non-static data member 'nr_piste'
>
> bool HardDisk[nr_piste][nr_sectoare];
>
> invalid use of non-static data member 'nr_sectoare'
>
> bool HardDisk[nr_piste][nr_sectoare];

Here is the code:

```
    class hard{
      public:
        int nr_piste, nr_sectoare, clusteri_ocupati;
        hard(){
            in >> nr_piste >> nr_sectoare >> clusteri_ocupati;
        }
        bool HardDisk[nr_piste][nr_sectoare];
        void insert(){
            int pista, sector;
            for (int i = 0; i < nr_piste; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < nr_sectoare; j++){
                    HardDisk[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < nr_piste; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < nr_sectoare; j++){
                    in >> pista >> sector;
                    HardDisk[pista][sector] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

I tried using putting the variables in private and that didn't work.

Comment: Post a [mcve] reproducing the problem as required here please.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a runtime variable to set array dimensions like that.

Even if you could, the array (a member variable) is created before the constructor runs!

So everything about this is impossible.

Try a vector instead, so that you can resize it as you need.

Comment: How can I declare a multidimensional vector?

Comment: @VladPoncea You can perform some research. This topic is exceptionally well-trodden.